# ValueError при попытке перейти loginout

Tags: python, django

При попытке перейти на */logout* вижу следующую ошибку :

```
ValueError at /user/logout/
The view User.views.logout_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Во **`views`** Import'ы все подключены как надо , код следующий :

```
def logout_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/')
```

Вот также файл `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: Очевидно, что вы переходите GET методом, а ваш код ожидает POST метод

Answer (score 1):

Да , действительно понял в чем именно заключалась ошибка, просто необходимо было именно в этом примере убрать проверку

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 0):

А если так?

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```